# Trouble with AWK'd command output and bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I am attempting to get a list of running VirtualBox VMs (the UUIDs) and put them into an array.  The command below produces the output below:

```
$ VBoxManage list runningvms | awk -F '[{}]' '{print $(NF-1)}' 

f93c17ca-ab1b-4ba2-95e5-a1b0c8d70d2a
46b285c3-cabd-4fbb-92fe-c7940e0c6a3f
83f4789a-b55b-4a50-a52f-dbd929bdfe12
4d1589ba-9153-489a-947a-df3cf4f81c69
```

I would like to take those UUIDs and put them into an array (possibly even an associative array for later use, but a simple array for now is sufficient)

If I do the following:

```
array1="( $(VBoxManage list runningvms | awk -F '[{}]' '{print $(NF-1)}') )"
```

The commands

```
array1_len=${#array1[@]}
echo $array1_len
```

Outputs "1" as in there's only 1 element.  If I print out the elements:

```
    echo ${array1[*]}
```

I get a single line of all the UUIDs

```
( f93c17ca-ab1b-4ba2-95e5-a1b0c8d70d2a 46b285c3-cabd-4fbb-92fe-c7940e0c6a3f 83f4789a-b55b-4a50-a52f-dbd929bdfe12 4d1589ba-9153-489a-947a-df3cf4f81c69 )
```

I did some research ([Bash Guide/Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) on how to tackle this and found this with command substitution and redirection, but it produces an empty array

```
while  read -r -d '\0'; do
        array2+=("$REPLY")
    done < <(VBoxManage list runningvms | awk -F '[{}]' '{print $(NF-1)}')
```

I'm obviously missing something.  I've looked at several simiar questions on this site such as:

- [Reading output of command into array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426529/reading-output-of-command-into-array-in-bash)
- [AWK output to bash Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056250/awk-output-to-bash-array)
- [Creating an Array in Bash with Quoted Entries from Command Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901513/creating-an-array-in-bash-with-quoted-entries-from-command-output)

Unfortunately, none have helped.  I would apprecaite any assistance in figuring out how to take the output and assign it to an array.

I am running this on macOS 10.11.6 (El Captain) and BASH version 3.2.57

Comment: Remove the double-quotes: `array1=( $(VBoxManage list runningvms | awk -F '[{}]' '{print $(NF-1)}') )`,  (The entries will be subject to word-splitting and pathname expansion but that doesn't appear to be a problem here.)

Comment: You were also very close with your `while`. If you change it to just: `while read -r; do`, it will work too.

Comment: @John1024 - the double quotes did it.  Out of curiosity, (even though it's moot), how would I approach this if there were spaces that led to word splitting since the quotes made the whole output a single long string?

Comment: @PesaThe - Thanks!  I thought I had to account for a null char based on what I read/understood).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on a Mac:

```
brew install bash
```

Then with this bash as your shell, pipe the output to:

```
readarray -t array1
```

Of the -t option, the man page says:

```
-t     Remove a trailing delim (default newline) from each line read.
```

If the bash4 solution is admissible, then the advice given
e.g. by gniourf_gniourf at [reading-output-of-command-into-array-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426529/reading-output-of-command-into-array-in-bash)
 is still sound.

Comment: It's a good solutions, however, I can't use it.  I don't like writing scripts that are dependent on specific  environments.  Many times, I share the script or I cannot install a port/brew making my solution unworkable.  I try to keep everything as native as possible.