# populate bash array with BLOCKS of lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have either a file (or the output of a command) that has block of lines separated by the empty line - like below:

```
1
2
3

4
5
6
```

cannot figure out how to populate bash (4.4.12) array with "block" of lines for each array cell, e.g.

```
arr[0]='
1
2
3'

array[1]='
4
5
6'
```

Looked around for similar threads with `readarray`, `mapfile`, played with `IFS/read` and other alternatives, but cannot figure out how to do the "blocks" of lines, not simply one-line-at-the time.
What's the magic combo?

Comment: you could replace every double newline \n\n with some other character (like \r) and use that as IFS

Comment: Don't tag `sh` for questions about features -- like arrays -- that aren't in the POSIX sh standard. You need to be using bash, ksh, zsh, or another extended shell for those (and obvs., details can vary depending on exactly which shell is in use).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy understood!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With bash:

```
declare -i c=0                      # set integer attribute

while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ -z $line ]] && c+=1
  arr[$c]+="$line"$'\n'
done < file

declare -p arr                      # output array
```

Output:

```
declare -a arr=([0]=$'1\n2\n3\n' [1]=$'\n4\n5\n6\n')
```

Comment: Nice; that's significantly cleaner than the approach I've historically taken, of appending items to the array only after accumulation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach on a similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63491435/store-each-occurence-found-by-awk-to-an-array):

```sh
while IFS= read -r -d '' rec
do
  arr2+=("${rec}")
done < <(awk '1' RS= ORS='\x0' file)

declare -p arr2
```